# Can I use Azure Policy to audit or enforce Azure Activity Log diagnostic settings?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, subscription, azure-eventhub, azure-log-analytics

Built in audits if a Log Profile exists, but not the destination stores. Would like to specify the Storage Account/Event Hub/Log Analytics Workspace.

Can I enforce those settings? In that approach, to also utilize modern diagnostic settings and send to a storage account and log analytics workspace.

Comment: What the type of resources are you looking to put this in place?

Answer (score 0):

Two (2) options to configure diagnostic settings (besides doing this manually on each resources):

**Azure Resource Template (ARM)**

This requires you to have a deeper understanding of Azure and Resources. However, it gives you all the flexibility to configure any type of resources and targets (storage, event hub or log analytics). This option does not come with additional feature to check compliancy and remediate any configuration drift.

See Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/diagnostic-settings-template)

**Azure Policy**

Configuration can be done through the portal (look for 'policy' under 'all services'). However, only the following resources are covered: Services Bus, Search Services, Event Hub, Stream Analytics, Data Lake Gen 1. On the other hand it comes with compliancy dashboard and remediation.

See Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/assign-policy-portal)